# Azure Managed Identity for App Service to access Key Vault in different tenant

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I'm working on a multi-tenant Azure environment where my App Service resides in Tenant A, and the Key Vault is located in Tenant B. I need to configure the App Service's Managed Identity to access secrets in the Key Vault from Tenant B.

I have already added the App Service's Managed Identity as an external user in Tenant B's Azure Active Directory, but I'm not sure how to grant it access to the Key Vault in Tenant B.

I've tried using the Key Vault access policies and adding the Managed Identity, but I can't find the external user (Managed Identity) from Tenant A in the list of available users in Tenant B's Key Vault.

Is there a way to configure a Managed Identity from one tenant (Tenant A) to access a Key Vault in another tenant (Tenant B)? If so, what are the necessary steps to achieve this?

In the above question, I tried to use the App Service's Managed Identity from Tenant A to access secrets in a Key Vault located in Tenant B. They expected to be able to grant the Managed Identity access to the Key Vault in Tenant B by adding it as an external user in Tenant B's Azure Active Directory and then configuring the Key Vault's access policies.

However, they encountered a problem when they were unable to find the external user (Managed Identity) from Tenant A in the list of available users in Tenant B's Key Vault access policies.

I am  seeking guidance on how to properly configure a Managed Identity from Tenant A to access a Key Vault in Tenant B and the necessary steps to achieve this.

Comment: Can you explain how you added the Managed Identity as an external user in tenant B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/managed-identities-faq#can-i-use-a-managed-identity-to-access-a-resource-in-a-different-directorytenant) states that you cannot use Managed identities across tenants.
The solution for you would be to use a Service principal.